# Deriving Binary tree from postorder or preorder listing

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I have a question regarding binary trees. so i know about preorder postorder and inorder that is used to construct the binary tree. Now how do i derive the inorder listing of a tree from a postorder listing of a tree or preorder listing of a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't derive an inorder listing from a postorder listing because postorder listing does not provide enough information about the shape of the tree. You need two listings (e.g. postorder and preorder) in order to uniquely reconstruct the tree.

A simple counterexample:

postorder listing : A B C

This can be one of two trees

```
    C
    |      C
    B     / \
    |    A   B
    A
```

but the inorder listings for these two trees are A B C and A C B.